# Excel not sorting dataset calculated with DATEVALUE

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm having a problem sorting by date from oldest to newest with a column that is calculated using the DATEVALUE function.

OS: MacOS 10.15.7
Excel: 16.44 (20102712)

I've imported a CSV file from a device and the date and time are all text. I'm converting them to separate columns using the DATEVALUE and TIMEVALUE functions. The resulting data computation using DATEVALUE is correct and produces a date serial number.

I'm trying to sort on the DateValue (Oldest to Newest) and TimeValue (smallest to largest), and when I set this sort, nothing happens, the order of the dataset is not changed.

Here is how the spreadsheet is laid out
[DateValueIssue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XxEX.png)

G column is using the following formula

```
=DATEVALUE(MID(A2,5,2)&"-"&LEFT(A2,3)&"-"&MID(A2,8,4))
```

H column is using the following formula

```
=TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(A2,8))
```

The file can be accessed at this link: [DateValueIssue.xlsx](https://drive.google.com/file/d/174Gx6n6ArUbIvdtDmJ9aseHUpG9VVyeS/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: The image is sorted by date and time in descending. Are you sure things aren't working okay? If you think some of the original text contents have spaces at the end, then you could change your time formula to: =TIMEVALUE(MID(A2,12,8))

Comment: Since Column G and H has formula therefore Excel usually unable to reshuffle the values,, better use column A to SORT since formula in G and H reads DATE as well TIME from Col A. Or create one HELPER column by splinting DATE from Column A to Sort.

Comment: @Isolated - the data output from the device is in reverse order - newest to oldest. I need to have it in oldest to newest - sorry should have mentioned that.

Comment: @RajeshS - "G and H has formula, therefore, Excel usually unable to reshuffle the values"

I was wondering if that was maybe the case. I have not encountered that before. So to understand - Excel can't sort columns that have formulas?

Comment: @karlgo,,, you have misinterpreted,, Excel does SORT the COLUMN had FORMULA but most of the times unable to rearrange the data in desire order,, you may try INDEX & MATCH for generating UNIQUE list and try to SORT,, you find how it behaves,, also  instead of DATEVALUE better use `=INT(A2)`,,, splits the DATE from DATETIME column A. And SORT it's working,,, and allow access to open the uploaded file on Goggle Drive & let me examine it !!

Answer (score 0):

- Before you sort, be sure the entire table is selected for the sort.
- Usually, that happens automatically when you select a cell in the table because the table is contiguous.
- In your case, column F is empty, so, if you select a cell in column G, for example, the auto-selected table only includes columns G:L.
- Since you are trying to sort on columns that contain a formula that depends on data that is OUTSIDE of the table, it will fail.

**Workarounds:**

1. Put a column Header in F1 or
2. Select the entire table in columns A:L before doing the sort.

Either method ensures that column A is included in the table, and your sort should work.

Comment: Thank you for posting your suggestions.

Can Excel sort columns that have formulas? I feel like I'm getting mixed messages.

Comment: @karlgo It depends. See above paragraph 4

Comment: @karlgo perhaps to be a bit more clear. It can sort the formula cells based on the value. But if the cell references are are referring to an unsorted column (a column outside the table); the sorting operation may not change what you visualize in the sorted column (although it will change the order in other columns that are part of the table and contain constants.